# Ajax call having Inner Join query in Eloquent Laravel 8 not working

Tags: mysql, ajax, laravel, eloquent, datatable

I wanted to fetch data from two tables using inner join in Laravel 8 and show it in front end as datatable by Ajax. But ajax call is returning internal server error.

Here is my controller

```
    if(request()->ajax()) {
        return datatables()->of(Machine::select("machine_base.id as id", "machine_base.machine_name as machine_name", "machine_base.machine_category as category_id", "item_category_base.category as category_name"))
            ->innerJoin("item_category_base", function($join){
            $join->on("item_category_base.id", "=", "machine_base.machine_category");
        })
        ->addIndexColumn()
            ->make(true);
    }
    return view('inventory.machine.machine_list');
```

Ajax Request:

```
 $('#dataList').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: "/inventory/machine-list",
        columns: [
            { data: 'DT_RowIndex', name: 'id' },
            { data: 'machine_name', name: 'machine_name'},
            { data: 'category_name', name: 'category_name'},
        ]
});
```

Equivalent mysql query which works fine:

```
SELECT machine_base.id as id, machine_base.machine_name as machine_name, machine_base.machine_category as category_id, item_category_base.category as category_name FROM machine_base
INNER JOIN item_category_base ON item_category_base.id = machine_base.machine_category
```

Select * statement is working fine using Eloquent. What I am missing please help me to find out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use join instead of innerjoin

```
if(request()->ajax()) {
    return datatables()->of(  Machine::select("machine_base.id as id", "machine_base.machine_name as machine_name", "machine_base.machine_category as category_id", "item_category_base.category as category_name")->join('item_category_base', 'item_category_base.id', '=', 'machine_base.machine_category'))
     
        ->addIndexColumn()
        ->make(true);
}
```

you can refer more about joins here
Ref:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#inner-join-clause